# How to get results from one table where ID from another table is not in the one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. `Table2` contains a FK from `table1`. Currently, my `table2` has FKs that don't exist in `table1` anymore. I'd like to remove those records from `table2` where the FK does not exist in `table1`. What is the SQL for that?

Here is the "NOT IN" I've tried:

```
SELECT ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.ATTY_ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.PRACTICE_GRP_ID 
FROM ATTORNEYS INNER JOIN ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS ON ATTORNEYS.[ATTY_ID] = ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[ATTY_ID] 
WHERE ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[ATTY_ID] NOT IN ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID
```

I probably don't know how to use "NOT IN" because the error is IN operator without () in expression.

I've tried using `!=`, `<>`, `NOT IN`, and `IS NULL` and no luck so far. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show us the SQL from your `NOT IN` attempt and explain how it failed ... include the full text of the error message.

Comment: I probably don't need to use the NOT IN operators, that was just something I tried.

Comment: Good that you showed us that SQL anyway.  Once you did, answers came in quickly. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID 
FROM ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS G
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = G.ATTY_ID)
```

This query will find any Attny_practice_group rows that have an ATTY_ID that isn't in ATTORNEYS.

Comment: NOT IN will also work but you need to do WHERE G.ATTY_ID NOT IN (SELECT ATTY_ID FROM ATTORNEYS).  NOT IN in this case is probably less efficient than NOT EXISTS though.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN in randcd's example would also suit your needs.

Comment: It can be replaced with a * or a column name or a 2 or a 3 or any number really.  Do "SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE (whereclause)" It'll select a 1 for each row that meets the WHERE criteria. In this case, if it finds a 1, the row exists.  The 1 doesn't really matter at all is the point I'm trying to get across.

Comment: Okay, so why put it in there? I'm just curious. I put 100 in there and it returned the exact same results.

Comment: I always used to put * but then I saw AaronBertrand using 1 and he's just way more knowledgeable than me so I started copying him.  I honestly do not think it matters in the slightest though.  Just a personal preference.  If you actually do a SELECT statement that returns results, though, using a 1 will probably be faster than an actual column because it won't have to look up any data at the leaf level of the index.  You can confirm this by checking two execution plans against each other.

Comment: Apparently I'm not very knowledgeable at all, lol. I don't know who Aaron Bertrand is or what an execution plan is.

Comment: He's a stackoverflow user/SQL Server expert with about 200k rep (compare to my 800).  The takeaway here is that the 1 isn't important in the context of a NOT EXISTS clause :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a LEFT JOIN.  Your INNER JOIN is only giveing you records you want to keep.  Your NOT IN statement won't return any results here.  Change your INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and select where ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[SomeColumn] IS NULL

so like this:

```
SELECT ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.ATTY_ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.PRACTICE_GRP_ID 
FROM ATTORNEYS LEFT JOIN ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS ON ATTORNEYS.[ATTY_ID] = ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[ATTY_ID] 
WHERE ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[ATTY_ID] IS NULL
```

Or perhaps I read it wrong.  If you are looking for Practice Groups that have an ATTY_ID that doesn't exist in the ATTORNEYS table, it would be like this:

```
SELECT ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.ID, ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.PRACTICE_GRP_ID, ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID 
FROM ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS LEFT JOIN ATTORNEYS ON ATTORNEYS.[ATTY_ID] = ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS.[ATTY_ID] 
WHERE ATTORNEYS.[ATTY_ID] IS NULL
```

Comment: IS NULL doesn't really work because there are values in the field. I was looking for the ones that exist in the ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS table that did not exist in ATTORNEYS. Aushin was able to take care of me.

Comment: In a LEFT JOIN, the "RIGHT" table value will be NULL for no match.